# can not import TensorFlow in Spyder or Python (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow')

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, spyder

I have tried to install both CPU and GPU version of TensorFlow according to the manual from here https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/ and all was ok:

> (tf-gpu) C:\Users\Kosh>conda create -n tf tensorflow Collecting
>   package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment:
>   done
>
> ==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==   current version: 4.7.12   latest version: 4.8.3
>
> Please update conda by running
>
> ```
> $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
> ```
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf
>
> added / updated specs:
>       - tensorflow
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> _tflow_select-2.2.0        |            eigen           3 KB
> tensorflow-2.1.0           |eigen_py37hd727fc0_0           4 KB
> tensorflow-base-2.1.0      |eigen_py37h49b2757_0        35.4 MB
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:        35.4 MB
> ```
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> _tflow_select      pkgs/main/win-64::_tflow_select-2.2.0-eigen
>   absl-py            pkgs/main/win-64::absl-py-0.9.0-py37_0   asn1crypto
>   pkgs/main/win-64::asn1crypto-1.3.0-py37_0   astor
>   pkgs/main/win-64::astor-0.8.0-py37_0   blas
>   pkgs/main/win-64::blas-1.0-mkl   blinker
>   pkgs/main/win-64::blinker-1.4-py37_0   ca-certificates
>   pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2020.1.1-0   cachetools
>   pkgs/main/noarch::cachetools-3.1.1-py_0   certifi
>   pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2020.4.5.1-py37_0   cffi
>   pkgs/main/win-64::cffi-1.14.0-py37h7a1dbc1_0   chardet
>   pkgs/main/win-64::chardet-3.0.4-py37_1003   click
>   pkgs/main/noarch::click-7.1.1-py_0   cryptography
>   pkgs/main/win-64::cryptography-2.8-py37h7a1dbc1_0   gast
>   pkgs/main/win-64::gast-0.2.2-py37_0   google-auth
>   pkgs/main/noarch::google-auth-1.13.1-py_0   google-auth-oauth~
>   pkgs/main/noarch::google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1-py_2   google-pasta
>   pkgs/main/noarch::google-pasta-0.2.0-py_0   grpcio
>   pkgs/main/win-64::grpcio-1.27.2-py37h351948d_0   h5py
>   pkgs/main/win-64::h5py-2.10.0-py37h5e291fa_0   hdf5
>   pkgs/main/win-64::hdf5-1.10.4-h7ebc959_0   icc_rt
>   pkgs/main/win-64::icc_rt-2019.0.0-h0cc432a_1   idna
>   pkgs/main/noarch::idna-2.9-py_1   intel-openmp
>   pkgs/main/win-64::intel-openmp-2020.0-166   keras-applications
>   pkgs/main/noarch::keras-applications-1.0.8-py_0   keras-preprocessi~
>   pkgs/main/noarch::keras-preprocessing-1.1.0-py_1   libprotobuf
>   pkgs/main/win-64::libprotobuf-3.11.4-h7bd577a_0   markdown
>   pkgs/main/win-64::markdown-3.1.1-py37_0   mkl
>   pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-2020.0-166   mkl-service
>   pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-service-2.3.0-py37hb782905_0   mkl_fft
>   pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_fft-1.0.15-py37h14836fe_0   mkl_random
>   pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_random-1.1.0-py37h675688f_0   numpy
>   pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-1.18.1-py37h93ca92e_0   numpy-base
>   pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-base-1.18.1-py37hc3f5095_1   oauthlib
>   pkgs/main/noarch::oauthlib-3.1.0-py_0   openssl
>   pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-1.1.1f-he774522_0   opt_einsum
>   pkgs/main/noarch::opt_einsum-3.1.0-py_0   pip
>   pkgs/main/win-64::pip-20.0.2-py37_1   protobuf
>   pkgs/main/win-64::protobuf-3.11.4-py37h33f27b4_0   pyasn1
>   pkgs/main/noarch::pyasn1-0.4.8-py_0   pyasn1-modules
>   pkgs/main/noarch::pyasn1-modules-0.2.7-py_0   pycparser
>   pkgs/main/noarch::pycparser-2.20-py_0   pyjwt
>   pkgs/main/win-64::pyjwt-1.7.1-py37_0   pyopenssl
>   pkgs/main/win-64::pyopenssl-19.1.0-py37_0   pyreadline
>   pkgs/main/win-64::pyreadline-2.1-py37_1   pysocks
>   pkgs/main/win-64::pysocks-1.7.1-py37_0   python
>   pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.7-h60c2a47_0_cpython   requests
>   pkgs/main/win-64::requests-2.23.0-py37_0   requests-oauthlib 
>   pkgs/main/noarch::requests-oauthlib-1.3.0-py_0   rsa
>   pkgs/main/noarch::rsa-4.0-py_0   scipy
>   pkgs/main/win-64::scipy-1.4.1-py37h9439919_0   setuptools
>   pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-46.1.3-py37_0   six
>   pkgs/main/win-64::six-1.14.0-py37_0   sqlite
>   pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.31.1-he774522_0   tensorboard
>   pkgs/main/noarch::tensorboard-2.1.0-py3_0   tensorflow
>   pkgs/main/win-64::tensorflow-2.1.0-eigen_py37hd727fc0_0
>   tensorflow-base
>   pkgs/main/win-64::tensorflow-base-2.1.0-eigen_py37h49b2757_0
>   tensorflow-estima~
>   pkgs/main/noarch::tensorflow-estimator-2.1.0-pyhd54b08b_0   termcolor 
>   pkgs/main/win-64::termcolor-1.1.0-py37_1   urllib3
>   pkgs/main/win-64::urllib3-1.25.8-py37_0   vc
>   pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4   vs2015_runtime
>   pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_1   werkzeug
>   pkgs/main/win-64::werkzeug-0.14.1-py37_0   wheel
>   pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.34.2-py37_0   win_inet_pton
>   pkgs/main/win-64::win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py37_0   wincertstore
>   pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37_0   wrapt
>   pkgs/main/win-64::wrapt-1.12.1-py37he774522_1   zlib
>   pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.11-h62dcd97_3
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages
>   _tflow_select-2.2.0  | 3 KB      | ############################################################################ | 100% tensorflow-2.1.0     | 4 KB      |
>
> ###################################################################### | 100% tensorflow-base-2.1. | 35.4 MB   |
>   
>   ###################################################################### | 100% Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done
>
> Executing transaction: done
>   #
>
> ## To activate this environment, use
>
> #
>
> ## $ conda activate tf
>
> #
>
> ## To deactivate an active environment, use
>
> #
>
> ## $ conda deactivate
>
> (tf-gpu) C:\Users\Kosh> (tf-gpu) C:\Users\Kosh> (tf-gpu)
>   C:\Users\Kosh>conda activate tf-2 Could not find conda environment:
>   tf-2 You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info
>   --envs`.
>
> (tf-gpu) C:\Users\Kosh>conda activate tf

but when I try to import it in Spyder or in Python I get the same result:

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me:

1. Run the anaconda prompt as administrator.(right click-> run as administrator).
2. pip uninstall tensorflow.
3. Close anaconda prompt.
4. Again run anaconda prompt as administrator.
5. type:
   conda install tensorflow
   It will ask for some y / n
   Type y.

Now after all done, change your python interpreter's environment to anaconda environment where you installed tensorflow.

After that tensorflow imported successfully!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using Python 3.7 and Tensorflow 2.1.

I created the environment tf-2 using `conda create -n tf-2 tensorflow pandas`.

There is no error using command prompt, but Spyder didn't find the Tensorflow library.

I verified that the IPython window was showing Python 3.6.9 (base version), while the command prompt was returning 3.7 to this command:

```
python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version())"
```

The reason were:

- the new environment didn't have Spyder installed;
- conda install Tensorflow 1.13 by default.

Then, I removed the environment tf2 and recreated it including the Python version and Spyder:

```
conda create -n tf2 python=3.6 spyder
```

Then, I installed tensorflow by pip.

```
conda activate tf2
pip install tensorflow
```